# Regular expressions in check constraint: does not accept numbers

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

How to add a constraint on column first_name (varchar2(20)) in customers table so that the value inserted in the column does not contain numbers?

I think I've found possible solution:

```
ALTER TABLE customers

ADD CONSTRAINT first_name_check

CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(first_name,'^[[:alpha:][:blank:][:cntrl:][:punct:]]+$')) NOVALIDATE;
```

Also:

```
ALTER TABLE customers

ADD CONSTRAINT first_name_check

CHECK (NOT REGEXP_LIKE(first_name,'[[:digit:]]')) NOVALIDATE;
```

However, is there better way to do it? Without using all those character classes and without "NOT" before REGEXP_LIKE?

I thought this would work:

```
ALTER TABLE customers

ADD CONSTRAINT first_name_check

CHECK (NOT REGEXP_LIKE(first_name,'^[^[:digit:]]+$')) NOVALIDATE;
```

But I was wrong. Could you explain me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the question "is there a better way to do it" regarding this constraint:

```
CHECK (NOT REGEXP_LIKE(first_name,'[[:digit:]]'))
```

It's a subjective question, so here's a subjective answer: I don't think so. It does the job, it's character-set safe, and it's easy to read (for a regex).

Answer (score 1):

Your last regexp doesn't seem quite right. `^[^[:digit:]]+$` should match any string that's not made up of digits, but then you invert the check.

Either get rid of the `NOT`, or try one more like this: `[$.*[:digit:].*^]` to match any sequence of characters, one digit, then any sequence of characters.

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed0ca/1).

Comment: I'm so confused! First, I'm afraid I've constructed my question badly. I want to reject any string that contains one or more numeral. For example: _'ab. d$'_ is ok but _'a9b'_ or _'9ab'_ or _'ab12'_ should be rejected. Now, let's take a look at my idea: `^[^[:digit:]]+$` doesn't `[^foobar]` means "anything but **not** _foobar_"? And therefore doesn't `[^[:digit:]]` means "anything but **not** `[:digit:]`"? Finally, looking at your idea: `[$.*[:digit:].*^]` doesn't it mean: anything that includes dollar sign or dot or asterisk or any digit or dot (repetition) or asterisk (repetition) or ^?